# Can't get Predictive Keyboard Emoji suggestions to show up in TextEditor/TextField

Tags: swiftui, textview, textfield, predictive

I have a simple `TextEditor` in my UI. But whenever the keyboard shows up and I type, I can't get the predictive toolbar on top of the keyboard to suggest emojis.

I tried with Instagram, Facebook, Twitter, Message app, Notes app they all work fine!

I have auto correction set to default (which is ON). I played with different `keyboardType(...)` to no avail. I'm using SwiftUI.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Oddly enough emojis started to show up automatically  — I feel it’s some AI on the device that detects if you use emojis in the textfield, at some point it’ll start to suggest them? I’d like to confirm that it’s the case with others.

[image]

Comment: Yes. You are correct it will show based on your past used emoji. here you can check in Use Predictive emoji section https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emojis started to show up automatically!

[image]